# Text alignment after wrapped figure

Tags: wrapfigure, alignment

After the wrapped figure, my text has a Center alignment. How can i return to the document's Format (i mean the text back on the left side) again? Thanks

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figures/fig5.png}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Steigung von der Sehne $[AB]$ als $B \rightarrow A$}
\end{wrapfigure}
$$
\begin{aligned} m_{T} &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1} \\ &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1} \\ &=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}(x+1) \quad \text { weil } x \neq 1 \\ &=2 \end{aligned}
$$
\par
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Definition von Ableitung
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l| }
\hline
    $f^{\prime}(a)$ ist die Steigung von der Tangente der Funktion $y=f(x)$ an dem Punkt wo
    \\ [0.5ex]  
    $x=a$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Rechenregeln von Ableitung}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Try using `\centering` instead of the `{center}` environment: [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/4301). Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Without a complete example it is difficult to test. But wrapfigure doesn't work well in the vincinity of lists (and both itemize and center are lists). I would be better to place this figure differently. And don't use $$ for display math, use ``\[.. \]``. $$ gives wrong spacing.